# How to create a complex multi-dimensional associative array?

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array

I'm currently creating a game where I want to store information about a Business, I do this through a multi-dimensional associative array so I have a list of the businesses and within the list key-value pairs of information.The array looks like this

```
Business.list =   {
        0.406411267183554: //First Business
            {
                capital : 5
                cash : 3 
                income: 3
                expenses : 6 
            },
        0.398198718278354:  //Second Business
            {
                capital : 6
                cash : 7 
                income: 3
                expenses : 7 
            }...

    };
```

Now I want to go one step deeper so that it now includes information about Upgrades. So within each Business, there will be information about all the upgrades that they have. These upgrades would be shown on the third level. I'm currently stumped on how I would programme this in Javascript. The way that I generate a business is by using Javascript Object Prototype.

```
    function Business(name, sector, capital, employees, type, id, efficiency) {
      var self = {
      name:name,  
      sector:sector,
      capital:capital,
      employees:employees,
      type:type,
      id:id,
      efficiency:efficiency,

     };
```

And then placing it into the list

```
    Business.list[id] = self;
```

Comment: and what does not work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but `self` variable is not accessible outside of `Business` function. Also, there's global `self`, which refers to `window`.

Comment: If you visit this site http://deano.me/2012/05/javascript-basic-multi-dimensional-associative-arrays/ on the "Arrays – Associative" you can see that the array goes deeper and is 3 levels compared to only two for mine. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var self = {
  name:name,  
  sector:sector,
  capital:capital,
  employees:employees,
  type:type,
  id:id,
  efficiency:efficiency,
  upgrades: ['CreditCard'] 
 };
```

and then

```
upgrades = Business.list[id].upgrades
```

or like this:

```
upgrades: {
    creditCard: false,
    cash: true 
}
```

Is this what you want ?

Comment: Ohh on the right track! Instead of credit card being an array I was looking more for it to be an associative array so that "CreditCard = False"

Comment: then just change it to object or array of objects :)

Comment: Ok done! Thanks :) The code is quite messy as I'm doing it like this: upgrades: {'CreditCard' : false }... Would it be possible to create an object outside and insert it into the business object?

Comment: Yes it can. You can have it done separately. When starting you may not even have upgrades at all, just assign it later on e.g. Business.list[id].upgrades={'CreditCard': true}